# How to save - restore all opengl state vars

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, state

Can I do anything I want between `glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS)` and `glPopAttrib()` and still do not harm the other code using - setting gl states before and after (do these functions provide complete isolation)?

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that if you do something that causes your application to crash (e.g. set a vertex pointer to `NULL` with no VBO bound and then try to draw), no amount of pushing and popping the proper state is going to help you there. So yes, it is still very much possible to harm the rest of the application even if you wrap this around it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that only pushes the ***server-side*** states onto the stack.

There are ***client-side*** states too, like pixel store and vertex arrays. For them, you have to use [`glPushClientAttrib (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushClientAttrib.xml).

While pixel store states are infrequently changed, vertex array state changes are very common in deprecated code. So if you want to do this properly, you need to save and restore both server and client state.